# css transition delay for display not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, delay, transition

I created a simple example here:
https://codepen.io/marekKnows_com/pen/LaRPZv

What I would like to do is display the red box 2 seconds AFTER the mouse hovers over the blue box.  When the mouse leaves the blue box, I want the red box to disappear immediately.

the HTML code looks like this:

```
<div id="blueBox">
</div>
<div id="redBox" class="">
</div>
```

The CSS code:

```
#blueBox {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
#redBox {
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: display 0s step-end 2s;
}
#redBox.isVisible {
  transition: display 0s step-end 0s;
  display: block;
}
```

and the JS code:

```
const el = document.getElementById( 'blueBox' );
const redEl = document.getElementById( 'redBox' );

el.addEventListener( 'mouseover', () => {
  redBox.classList.add( 'isVisible' );
});

el.addEventListener( 'mouseout', () => {
  redBox.classList.remove( 'isVisible' );
});
```

What I'm seeing is the red box doesn't wait the 2 seconds before making the redbox appear.  Why?

Comment: [The "display" property cannot be animated.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)

Comment: `display` is not an animatable property in CSS. You might want to consider using `opacity`.

Answer (score 1):

Use visiblity property for this as you cannot do transition with display property.

Comment: thank you all! I switched to using opacity and now I have it working as expected.

Comment: You can not with `visibility` alone as well.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava We can do that with visibility. Try out above example with below css. (Note: You have to remove transition property from #redBox.isVisible as it is not required here. It is only required to be set in #redBox):```#blueBox {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
#redBox {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: visibility 0s step-end 2s;
}
#redBox.isVisible {
  visibility: visible;
}```

Comment: I guess I meant a smooth visual transition instead of show/hide.